# Ruby equivalent of Java Bouncy Castle AES-128-CBC padding

Tags: java, ruby, openssl, bouncycastle

I'm writing some Ruby code to decrypt messages encoded using Java Bouncy Castle with AES 128 bit CBC with PKS#5 padding and default initialisation vector.

I'm using Ruby Open::SSL, with the default padding, which is apparently PKS#5. I can decrypt short messages, but not long messages.

For debugging I've used Ruby Open::SSL to encrypt the same messages as Java Bouncy Castle is encryting and I see that the first block of characters, up to what's added in #final, is exactly the same.

So I'm guessing that there's a difference in the padding used. But the default padding in both Ruby and Bouncy Castle is PKS#5. In Ruby there doesn't seem to be any way to change the padding, except for the cryptic (appropriately as this is encryption) comment in the manual "See EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding for further information.". There's no entry for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding and Googling it doesn't give any clue about what to set and when.

Has anyone managed to encrypt something in Java Bouncy Castle and decrypt it in Ruby?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I need the same info.

Comment: No. I gave up. We used an api call into a Java service to do the job. Which is a shame because I would have preferred to do it in Ruby. But it seems that there is something non-standard about the Ruby implementation of AES-128-CBC.

Answer (score 0):

Googling works: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding.html

> Enables or disables padding

You cannot pick other padding then default (most probably PKCS#7 [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677550/does-ruby-aes-use-padding-by-default))

We don't have options like C#:

> ANSIX923  4    The ANSIX923 padding string consists of a sequence of
> bytes filled with zeros before the length.
>
> ISO10126  5    The ISO10126 padding string consists of random data before
> the length.
>
> PKCS7 2    The PKCS #7 padding string consists of a sequence of bytes,
> each of which is equal to the total number of padding bytes added.
>
> Zeros 3    The padding string consists of bytes set to zero.

Comment: explanation of padding styles: https://asecuritysite.com/symmetric/padding